# Ionic Local Notifications have the wrong app name

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

This is probably something really simple that I've overlooked but I just wanted to check.

I've set up Local Notifications in my Ionic 2 app and everything is working ok except for the App Name in the Notification. It seems to be using the old name `my-app` rather than `My App`. I'm testing in the iOS emulator.

I've changed the name in `config.xml` and the `ionic.config.json` files. I've also tried the following to no avail:

`cordova plugin save
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
ionic build ios`

Could there be anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Cancel all local notifications when you update or install the app:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Make sure you call CancelAllLocalNotifications only once, otherwise it can result in unexpected behaviour.

By doing this, the local notifications who were fired by the old app will be canceled and the new local notifications will br configured with the new app name.